# Failed to install discord module on dietpi Raspberry pi 4

Tags: python-3.x, linux, raspberry-pi, discord.py, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to install the discord module, but my raspberry is not cooperating. I need the discord module to run the class discord bot for homework. I deleted all copy and replaces, because of stackoverflow limitations of code and sent only warnings and errors.

error:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: multidict, yarl
  Building wheel for multidict (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmp1z1tiv8h
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-rrd10h4t/multidict
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict/_multidict.html'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict/*.so'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict/*.pyd'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict/*.pyd'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
  arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c multidict/_multidict.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.7/multidict/_multidict.o -O2 -std=c99 -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wconversion -fno-strict-aliasing -pedantic
  error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for multidict
  Building wheel for yarl (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmpwsi1qkco
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-rrd10h4t/yarl
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.cache' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl/*.html'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl/*.so'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl/*.pyd'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
  writing manifest file 'yarl.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

  arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c yarl/_quoting_c.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.7/yarl/_quoting_c.o
  error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for yarl
Failed to build multidict yarl
ERROR: Could not build wheels for multidict, yarl which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I can't find any help on the internet.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64762931/python-discord-py-error-could-not-build-wheels-for-multidict-yarl-which-use-p

Comment: Yes thank you. I downloaded newest python 3.8.X source code and compiled it. It started working and bot is running now for 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the newest python 3.8.x source code and compiled it. (I lost the link, but you can find it on google "how to install python 3.8.6 on raspberry pi"). It is working now.